# Enter cyclic page numbers as footers in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a 200-page-long document. I want to mark the footers such that the first page reads 'Page 1 of 2', the second page reads 'Page 2 of 2', and again the third should read '1 of 2' and so on.

I am trying to use a VBA script as I don't want to use 'different first page' and then give section breaks every two pages.

```vb
Sub InsertCyclicFooters()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    n = 2
    
    For Each sec In doc.Sections
        Set rng = sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        
        i = rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        
        i = (i - 1) Mod n + 1
        
        rng.Text = "Page " & i & " of " & n
        
        sec.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Next sec
    
    doc.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

This script marks each page as 'Page 1 of 2'.

I tried updating the fields with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: As you can see from your code the footer is a child of the section. To achieve what you want you need to insert a section break after each second page. Given that your footer only consists of text logically it will be the same text on every page of the section. I suggest that you first learn how to do this in the UI before you try to write code. Add a page number field to your footer and set page numbers to restart in each section. There is no need for a different first page, unless your document is a collection of letters that need a letterhead page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

```vb
Sub InsertCyclicFooters()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim rng As Range, rngGoto As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim pageCount As Long, ur As UndoRecord
    
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "InsertCyclicFooters"
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    n = 2
    
    pageCount = doc.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
    
    Set rng = doc.Characters(1)
    Do While i < pageCount
        i = rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        Set rngGoto = rng.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToNext, 1)
'        Do Until rngGoto.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) = i + 1
'            rngGoto.Move Count:=-1
'        Loop
        
        If i < pageCount Then
            rngGoto.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
            Set rng = rng.Document.Sections(n).Range.Characters(1)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Loop
    
    n = 2
    Set rngGoto = doc.Characters(1)
    For Each sec In doc.Sections
        
        sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
        Set rng = sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        
        
        'i = rng.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        i = rngGoto.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        
        i = (i - 1) Mod n + 1
        
        rng.Text = "Page " & i & " of " & n
        
        'sec.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
        Set rngGoto = rng.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToNext, 1)
        
    Next sec
    
    doc.Fields.Update
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this just using field codes (and no section breaks if you prefer). e.g., assuming the pages are actually numbered 1,2,3,4,...

```
Page { 1+MOD({ PAGE }+1,2) } of 2
```

or, removing spaces,

```
Page{1+MOD(({PAGE}+1,2)} of 2
```

Whether you do it using fields or VBA+fields, that should be OK for an even number of pages, e.g. 200. If you actually have an odd number, you would presumably need to do something special at the end to give you `Page 1 of 1` (a section break would probably be the simplest approach for that).

*All* the {} need to be the special field code brace pairs that you can enter on Windows desktop Word using ctrl-F9.